# How to display large amounts of data in an RDLC TextBox

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc

I have an rdlc report which displays transcribed information retrieved from a single text field in a Microsoft SQL 2008 database. The report is simple in that it consists of a short header, and a body which contains a single textbox. The issue we are having is some of the report data is cut off. No error message just cut off. After some testing we determined the textbox cuts off around 32,000 characters. After this discovery I did some research and the only thing I found useful was a reference to msdn [social.msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/sqlreportingservices/thread/95ACD8B0-C4F8-405A-961E-AC5EA0CB8CF4)
Some of the transcriptions we are running into contain 500,000 characters and we have no way to know if that will not go up. Is there any way around what appears to be the report’s textbox 32,000 character limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I came up with was to write some T-SQL to break up the large block of text
into smaller pieces, and then return a table containing a row for every 30,000 char block of text. Then on the report place my textbox in a list. 
Below is the SQL

```
declare @transcriptionBody TABLE 
(
    SegmentNumber int identity(1,1),
    BodyPart nvarchar(max)
)
declare 
    @bodyPart varchar(max),
    @body nvarchar(max),
    @indexToLastNewLineInBodyPart int,
    @lenOfBody int,
    @MAX_CHARACTERS int,
    @numberOfCharactersLeftInString int,
    @position int

set @MAX_CHARACTERS = 30000
set @indexToLastNewLineInBodyPart = 0
set @numberOfCharactersLeftInString = 0
set @position = 0

/*
 *  Get the long string of characters from your database. In this example the 
 *  [Body] field is a text field.
*/
select @body = Body from [Transcription] with(nolock) where Id = @TranscriptionId
set @lenOfBody = len(@body)

/*
 *  Loop through the @body variable chopping up the string into managable chuncks
 *  and inserting those chuncks into a table variable called @transcriptionBody.
 *  The loop exists when the 
*/
while (@position < @lenOfBody)
begin

    /*
     *  If the transcription body is less than 30,000 then insert it into
     *  our table variable and return.
    */
    if (@lenOfBody <= @MAX_CHARACTERS and @position = 0)
    begin
        insert into @transcriptionBody(BodyPart) values(@body)
        set @position = @lenOfBody
    end

    /*
     *  Otherwise we need do the following
     *  1.  Get the number of chars in the string starting from the input start index.
     *  2.  If the number of chars in the string is > than the max allowable chars then
     *      substring off the first 30,000 chars into a body part.
     *      
     *      2a. Now have a string consisting of 30,000 chars but you have no idea where it
     *          cut off (it could be in the middle of a word). So you now need to get the 
     *          index of the last newline and re-break the string on that.Then insert it
     *          into the table variable and set the position.
     *
     *  3.  If the number of chars in the string IS NOT > than the max allowable chars
     *      then substring off the remaining chars into a body part and insert it into our
     *      table variable
    */
    else
    begin
        -- 1.
        select @numberOfCharactersLeftInString = (@position - @lenOfBody) * -1

        -- 2.
        if (@numberOfCharactersLeftInString > @MAX_CHARACTERS)
        begin
            select @bodyPart = substring(@body, @position, @MAX_CHARACTERS)

            -- 2a.
            select @indexToLastNewLineInBodyPart = Len(@bodyPart) - charindex(char(13)+char(10),reverse(@bodyPart))
            if (@indexToLastNewLineInBodyPart > 0)
            begin
                select @bodyPart = substring(@bodyPart,@position,@indexToLastNewLineInBodyPart)
                insert into @transcriptionBody(BodyPart) values(@bodyPart)
                select @position = @position + len(@bodyPart)
            end     
        end
        else
        begin
            select @bodyPart = substring(@body, @position, @numberOfCharactersLeftInString)
            insert into @transcriptionBody(BodyPart) values(@bodyPart)
            select @position = @position + len(@bodyPart)
        end 
    end
end
select * from @transcriptionBody order by SegmentNumber
```